# Is there a way to create a template jquery function and apply to various classes or id's?

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote some jQuery to perform some routine functions on various repeated html elements. This will get quite padded and, in my opinion, unnecessary. For example the code below is the same jQuery workflow repeated with the same html, only the html content will differ:

```
$("#open_add_user").click(function() {
    $(".add_user").removeClass("hidden").width("85%").children().hide().fadeIn(500);
});

$("#close_add_user").click(function() {
    $(".add_user").width("0").children().fadeOut(300);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".add_user").addClass("hidden"); 
    }, 400);
});

$("#open_add_client").click(function() {
    $(".add_client").removeClass("hidden").width("85%").children().hide().fadeIn(500);
});

$("#close_add_client").click(function() {
    $(".add_client").width("0").children().fadeOut(300);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".add_client").addClass("hidden"); 
    }, 400);
});
```

In this case this jQuery will be applied for both clients and users, but many other classes may be added, thus meaning that the code will be duplicated multiple times. Is there any way in which this code could be made condensed and only called by classes that require this code?

In this scenario, this is what the HTML code would look like, however the question is based on the concept and not necessarily pertaining to this code:

```
<div id="users_database_content">       
    <div class="data_table">
        <table id="users_database_table">

        </table>            
    </div>
    <button id="open_add_user" class="button_1">Add User</button>
</div>



<div class="right_panel hidden add_user">
    <button id="close_add_user" class="button_1">Close</button>

    <div class="box">
        <form>
            <div class="input_table">                           
                <table>
                </table>
            </div>                      
            <button type="button" name="" class="button_1">Register</button>
            <button type="button" class="button_3">Cancel</button>              
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Pass in the desired element as a function parameter? You would need to provide your markup for us to be able to tell you how to do that though; how does `#open_add_user` correlate to `.add_user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper function:

```
function FadeIn(elementStr)
{
 $(elementStr).removeClass("hidden").width("85%").children().hide().fadeIn(500);
}

function FadeOut(elementStr)
{
    $(elementStr).width("0").children().fadeOut(300);
      setTimeout(function(){
         $(elementStr).addClass("hidden"); 
     }, 400);
 }
```

Then what you can do is

```
$("#close_add_client").click(function() { FadeOut(".add_client"); });
$("#open_add_client").click(function() { FadeIn(".add_client"); });
```

This should cut your code down considerably, and make it more "dry"

Comment: Will definitely do, just waiting for another possible solution or two in order to select the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your logic by modifying your markup to tell your smaller script what it should do.  In the example below, I gave some elements classes to lookup, and the one button has a data field so it knows what element to target.  Using this logic, so long as you follow the pattern of putting the classes on the right elements, and set the data element correctly, it will expand to any number of elements, without requiring you to duplicate any of the javascript logic.

Comments are included in the code below...

```js
// give the elements a common class, rather than different ids, to generalize the logic
$(".bind-open-add").on("click", function() {
  var $openAdd = $(this);
  
  // the bind-open-add button has a "data-add-area" on it that tells us the
  // class of the secondary div that should be changed
  $("."+ $openAdd.data("addArea"))
    .removeClass("hidden")
    .width("85%")
    .children()
      .hide()
      .fadeIn(500);
});

// give the elements a common class, rather than different ids, to generalize the logic
$(".bind-close-add").on("click", function() {
  var $closeAdd = $(this);
  // the add_user has been given a common class of "bind-close-add-container"
  // that we can get with closest
  var $closeAddContainer = $closeAdd.closest(".bind-close-add-container");
  
  $closeAddContainer
    .width("0")
    .children()
      .fadeOut(300);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $closeAddContainer.addClass("hidden");
  }, 400);
});
```

```html
<div id="users_database_content">
  <div class="data_table">
    <table id="users_database_table"></table>
  </div>
  
  <button id="open_add_user"
          class="bind-open-add button_1"
          data-add-area="add_user">Add User</button>
</div>

<div class="right_panel hidden add_user bind-close-add-container">
  <button id="close_add_user" class="bind-close-add button_1">Close</button>

  <div class="box">
    <form>
      <div class="input_table">
        <table></table>
      </div>
      
      <button type="button" name="" class="button_1">Register</button>
      <button type="button" class="button_3">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```